# PHP Read Byte Range from String or File

Tags: php

I am looking for a method that may or may not exist in PHP.

I am wanting to read a file or string given a starting and ending position in bytes.

To explain lets say I have a string or file of length 300 bytes. I have a value that I know is 46 bytes into the string/file and terminates 55 bytes in. How could read just this section?

Edit: I have found [this on GitHub](https://github.com/rvflorian/byte-serving-php) which may help to solve my problem but will need to explore it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [`fseek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and [`fread`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

```
<?php
$byteOffset = 1024;
$readLength = 256;
$fileHandle = fopen('myfile', 'r');
fseek($fileHandle, $byteOffset);
$bytes = fread($fileHandle, $readLength);
```